# How to set default value in material-UI select box in react (after API call)?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I try to use [Select Box](https://material-ui.com/api/select/) from MUI
All really simple, like in an [MUI demo](https://next.material-ui.com/components/selects/#main-content)

Just one thing, my default value comes after an API call.
So, I need to 'Update' the default value.
After 5 sec the value of 'age' is updated to 30, but the select box doesn't.
How to fix it?

```js
    const [age, setAge] = React.useState<number>();
    
      React.useEffect(() => {
        //Emulate API call
        setTimeout(() => {
          setAge(30);
        }, 5000);
      }, []);
    
      const handleChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<{ value: unknown }>) => {
        setAge(event.target.value as any);
      };
    
      return (
        <Box sx={{ minWidth: 120 }}>
          <FormControl fullWidth>
            <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">Age</InputLabel>
            <Select
              labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
              id="demo-simple-select"
              value={age}
              label="Age"
              onChange={handleChange}
            >
              <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
            </Select>
          </FormControl>
          Current Age: {age}
        </Box>
      );
```

code on sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/basicselect-material-demo-api-call-7k46b?file=/demo.tsx

Answer (score 3):

You just need to get rid of initial undefined value of age.
You can see the error in the console that undefined is out of the options range value.

```
const [age, setAge] = React.useState<number | ''>('');
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. Just need to initialize the value.   
`const [age, setAge] = React.useState<number>(0); `   
Is enough.